# Unique links in Mechanical Turk External Survey

Tags: mechanicalturk

Amazon's mTurk lets you have the HIT (task) as basically "Click on this link to an external website, complete the survey, and then paste the code it gives you here."

Is there any way instead to generate a list of unique URLs, and have each worker shown a different URL?

I'd settle for being about to insert the worker ID into the URL.

Comment: Do you want each worker to only see one of the HITs (thus only one of the URLs)?

Comment: Why dont you just create a separate HIT for each link and open each HIT to one worker?

Comment: Good idea JRobinson, I guess the only disadvantage of that is it is maybe a bit harder to manage from the web UI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be accomplished by creating your own ExternalHit as an iframe linked to your website and on your website extract the WorkerId from the querystring that Amazon appends to the your website's URL.

I do not believe this can be done via the Amazon Web front end.

Alternately, [TurkPrime.com](http://www.turkprime.com) (an Amazon Partner) has a free and convenient UI for creating external HITs and you can contact them for your particular use case.

Disclaimer: I help develop that site.